# Несколько языков на сайте Django

Tags: python, django

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с этой темой.
Переводы сделал
получил файлы .po и .mo
при смене в settings.py LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru' на LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en' и обновлении страницы все переводится и работает.
Как добавить чтобы была возможность на главной странице выбирать какой язык использовать 
Добавил в urls.py

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('registers.urls')),
)
```

И шаблон смены языков в base.html

```
 {% load i18n %}
 {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}    
 {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}    
 {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}    
 <div class="languages">      
  <p>{% trans "Language" %}:</p>      
  <ul class="languages">        
    {% for language in languages %}          
    <li>           
      <a href="/{{ language.code }}/" {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} class="selected"{% endif %}>            
      {{ language.name_local }}          
    </a>        
  </li>      
 {% endfor %}    
 </ul>  
 </div>
```

в адрессной строке теперь меняется url  на ru и en  но перевод не делается, подскажите в чем проблема
при этом если использовать перевод простых фраз как  {%trans 'Отправить' %} фраза переводится при выборе языка английского
не переводятся только названия которые перевожу в forms.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
date_visit = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'], label=_('Дата'))
```

Подскажите почему так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем отвечу сам на свой вопрос.
вместо `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`
написал `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`
и все работает, может будет кому интересно

Answer (score 1):

Что происходит, когда Вы используете `ugettext()` (вместо `ugettext_lazy()`) в `models.py` (скажем, на `verbose_name`):

1. Django запускается, язык по умолчанию - *английский*;
2. Django выбирает *английскую версию* `verbose_name`;
3. Пользователь меняет язык сайта на *русский*;
4. `verbose_name` по-прежнему отображается на *английском языке* (потому что определение поля вызывается только один раз; и к моменту вызова язык был другим).

Чтобы избежать этого, необходимо использовать `ugettext_lazy()`.

Краткая информация о том, когда следует использовать функции `ugettext()` или `ugettext_lazy()`:

- `ugettext_lazy()`:

  - `models.py (fields, verbose_name, help_text, методы short_description)`;
  - `forms.py (labels, help_text, empty_label)`;
  - `apps.py (verbose_name)`.
- `ugettext()`:

  - `views.py`;
  - Другие модули, похожие на `views.py`, которые выполняются в процессе запроса.

[Перевел часть из этой статьи.](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/10/17/django-tip-18-translations.html)